# Диалог загрузки картинок, нету предпросмотра

Tags: linux, dialog, xfce, thumbnails, cinnamon

Вроде и проблема старая, но инфы по ней мало. При открытии файлов, в частности картинок нету предпросмотра.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это актуально для телеграмма, но превью отображается, например, в фаерфоксе.
Ребята с чатика по федоре посоветовали перейти на cinnamon, но там проблема та же. Правда, вместо значка отображается маленькая картинка, но разобрать что-то сложно.

Для PureRef ситуация похожая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли способ как исправиль все это? Нашел, что это "особенность" GTK-3 и поделать с этим ничего нельзя. Так ли это. Очень неудобно.

Comment: А когда сеткой включаете отображение, тоже нет предпросмотра (это по-русски preview)?

Comment: @0andriy, нету все-равно

Comment: какой файловый менеджер используется? nemo, nautilus, thunar? В каждом из них настройки индивидуальны. Я пробовал с Thunar - при доустановке пакета tumbler-plugins-extra превьюшки появились.

Comment: @Alex_Krug, Thunar

Comment: если thunar - доставляете вышеуказанный пакет, выходите и заходите по новой - все появляется

Comment: @Alex_Krug, Нету такого пакета, есть tumbler-extras. Установка не помогла

Comment: не знаю, по крайней мере, для Ubuntu есть для всех версий - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tumbler-plugins-extra
я так понимаю, что у Вас Fedora (хотя надо было сразу указать)? похоже, нужно tumbler-0.2.9-1.fc33.x86_64.rpm  https://fedora.pkgs.org/33/fedora-x86_64/tumbler-0.2.9-1.fc33.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: @Alex_Krug, все поставил, превьюшек нету.